CodeIgniter 4-Nginx Server 404
Estoy tratando de hacer un sitio web con VTiger usando CodeIgniter 4, Composer con base de datos MySQL
Hice la instalación siguiendo las instrucciones de la documentación de CodeIgniter, pero no encuentro el error. El problema es cuando entro en la página de login y escribo mi acceso que está funcionando porque no me sale un error de credenciales incorrectas. La página solo me muestra 404 not found, previamente me indicaba 401 antes de ajustar mi conf de nginx
Este es mi archivo .conf de nginx
server {
    root /var/www/html/mydomain.com/;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log debug;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
        if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name mydomain.com;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    # return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

Revisé las extensiones necesarias para PHP y las habilité, aquí está mi php info PHP INFO
Sé que es muy difícil encontrar el problema, pero tal vez alguien con más experiencia puede ayudarme a solucionarlo o para saber por dónde puedo empezar
Si necesita más información acerca de mi configuración, por favor hágamelo saber
